# how to send data from ajax get method to controller in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Proceed to booking
on clicking the button i call the ajax function code below

```
$("#add_cart").click(function() 
    {$.ajax({
              url: 'roombooking',
              type: "get",
              data: {id:data},
               success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
              if(data == "success")
               alert(response); 
               }
               });
              });
```

Route

```
Route::post('roombooking','pagescontroller@roombooking');
```

Controller

```
public function roombooking($id,request $req)
    {

       $input = $req->all();
       return view ('pages.roombooking')->with('id',$id);
    }
```

Comment: what is your question? You have an ajax GET but your route is POST

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('roombooking','pagescontroller@roombooking');
```

change to

```
Route::get('roombooking','pagescontroller@roombooking');
```

Comment: i did it but still m not able to redirect to another view

Comment: What do you mean?
You send request by ajax and need to redirect to another view?
even though you can use location.href in javascript to redirect page, but why you need to do it?

Comment: I have a page that list data in bootstrap table with checkbox . So now when the user checks in multiple item from the table i want  those item id to be send to the controller through ajax and in the controller i will check the id in the database and fetch my desired data  and in another view want to list those data. please help... also if there is any alternative -

Comment: So please show the error you got. If you use form then submit, remember stop the default event (event.preventDefault()) before sending data by ajax